# ¿Cómo usar tablas pivotes en laravel 5.2?

Tags: laravel-5

¿Alguien puede darme una asesoría  de los métodos para tablas pivotes: **agregar**, **editar** y **eliminar** registros en en dichas tablas? Sólo requiero explicación básica.

Comment: ¿qué no entiendes de los ejemplos de la documentación?

Comment: necesito relacionar mi tabla users con las tablas regiones, estados , ciudades, en una sola tabla pivote, en este caso se debe declarar una relación por cada tabla?

Comment: No veo la necesidad de una tabla pivote, un usuario estaría relacionado con más de una ciudad?

Comment: si, en este caso seria como un supervisor, viene siendo una estructura de árbol region->estado->ciudad->inmueble